# Determine if the following sets are linear subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I was given the following assignment to solve, but I really can't think think about how to solve it... Can anybody help me?

Verify if each set below is a linear subspace.

$(a)\{A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \vert A^T = A\}$

$(b)\{x \in \mathbb{R}^3\vert x_3=x_1\cdot x_2\}$

Comment: But on exercise (a), for instance, what is the subset? A?$A^T$?

Comment: @user46944 $0 \in A$ is not technically a separate condition to the second two

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment, it seems that you're having trouble making sense of the question.

First of all, let's makes sense of the set.  We have $S = \{A \in \Bbb R^{n \times n} \mid A^T = A\}$.  In words, we have "$S$ is the set of $n \times n$ matrices (with real entries) that are equal to their own transpose".

So, for example, in the case of $n = 2$, we could say that 
$
(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{smallmatrix}) \in S
$, but
$
(\begin{smallmatrix}1&3\\0&2\end{smallmatrix}) \notin S.
$

We want to check whether $S$ is a linear subspace.  That is, we need to check if the following are true:

- if $A \in S$ and $B \in S$, is it true that $A + B \in S$?
- if $A \in S$ and $k \in \Bbb R$, is it true that $kA \in S$?

$S$ is a linear subspace exactly when both of the above statements are true for *every* choice of $A$, $B$, and $k$.

I claim that, in this case, $S$ is a linear subspace.  How can we show that this is true?

---

Now, I claim that the set $S' = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^3\vert x_3=x_1\cdot x_2\}$ is **not** a linear subspace.  Can you find an example of an element (or elements) of $S'$ that fail the necessary condition?

Comment: $A = \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{21} & \ldots & a_{n1}\\ 
a_{21} & a_{22} & \ldots & a_{n2}\\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \\ 
a_{n1} & a_{n2} &  & a_{nn}
\end{bmatrix},
B = \begin{bmatrix}
b_{11} & b_{21} & \ldots & b_{n1}\\ 
b_{21} & b_{22} & \ldots & b_{n2}\\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \\ 
b_{n1} & b_{n2} &  & b_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: and $C = A + B = \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}+b_{11} & a_{21}+b_{21} & \ldots & a_{n1}+b_{n1}\\ 
a_{21}+b_{21} & a_{22}+b_{22} & \ldots & a_{n2}+b_{n2}\\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \\ 
a_{n1}+b_{n1} & a_{n2}+b_{n2} &  & a_{nn}+b_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}$
Is this enough to prove that $C \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ ?

Comment: Is it clear that $C$ is equal to its own transpose?

Comment: @user46944 pay attention to the subscripts he used

Comment: @Frank so yes, what you did is enough to prove that $C \in S$, which is what I *think* you meant to ask.

Comment: Also, having $k \in \mathbb{R},
\\
D = k \cdot A = \begin{bmatrix}
k \cdot a_{11} & k \cdot a_{21} & \ldots & k \cdot a_{n1}\\ 
k \cdot a_{21} & k \cdot a_{22} & \ldots & k \cdot a_{n2}\\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \\ 
k \cdot a_{n1} & k \cdot a_{n2} &  & k \cdot a_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}
\\
D \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ would prove the other condition, right?

Comment: @Frank Do you mean $D \in S$?

Comment: Yes... And I also meant that $C \in S$

Comment: @Frank also `pmatrix{stuff & stuff\\ stuff & stuff}` is much easier for MathJax things.

Comment: Then yes! That does it.  You're all set for the first part.

Comment: About the second part... $(b)
\vec{u}= (x_1,y_1,x_1y_1), \vec{v} = (x_2,y_2,x_2y_2), S = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^3 \vert x_3=x_1x_2\}
\\
\text{We have that } \vec{w} = \vec{u} + \vec{v} = (x_1+y_1,x_2+y_2,x_1y_1+x_2y_2)
\\
\boldsymbol{\vec{w} \not\in S}
\\
k \in \mathbb{R}, k \cdot \vec{u} = (k \cdot x_1, k \cdot y_1, k \cdot x_1y_1)
\\
\boldsymbol{k \cdot \vec{u} \not\in S}$Therefore, the given set is not a subspace

Comment: @Frank just give one example.  For example, $u = (1,1,1)$ and $k=2$.